# Energy magnetization in the presence of temperature and chemical potential gradient

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In the following paper (Phys. Rev. Lett. 97, 026603)

http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.97.026603

the energy magnetization part of the energy current is given in the presence of electric field as $-\mathbf{E}\times \mathbf{M}$ with a uniform temperature and chemical potential being assumed. The transport energy current is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{j}^E=\mathbf{J}^E+\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{M}
\end{equation}

I wonder whether there are expressions for energy magnetization part of the energy current in the presence of temperature and chemical potential gradient so that one might recover Wiedemann-Franz law for anomalous thermal Hall effect?

Comment: Maybe I should ask this question in a different way: How to write down the expression for anomalous energy (or heat) current in the presence of temperature or chemical potential gradient?

Comment: Landauer equation might get you some part of the way. It deals with nanoscale transport due to differences in distribution functions.